# How to monitor login time and logout time and storing into mysql database using java API's

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, monitoring, tracking

**I'm Trying whenever user logged into the system, that particular username and current time will captured and stored into MySQL database. And my Database Table Names is userName, systemLoginTime, systemLogoffTime. I've tried so many times, but when the user logs into the system it is not effected in Database**

```
This is my code java API:

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String userName = "";
        String systemLoginTime = "";
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/insert/{userName}/{systemLoginTime}");
        //Insert your JSON query request
        String query = "{'userName':USERNAME,'systemLoginTime':'TODAY'}";
        //It change the apostrophe char to double colon char, to form a correct JSON string
        query=query.replace("'", "\"");

        try{
            System.getenv().get("USERNAME");
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
        //com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName;
    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    System.out.println("username = " + username);
    //make connections
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            //It Content Type is so importan to support JSON call
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            printMessage("Your URL: " + url.toString());
            //use post mode
            urlc.setDoOutput(true);
            urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

            //send query
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
            ps.print(query);
            printMessage("Your Query: " + query);
            ps.close();

            //get result
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
            String l = null;
            while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
               printMessage(l);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            printMessage("Error ocurred");
            printMessage(e.toString());
        }

    }

    private static void printMessage(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

 }
```

=====================================

```
This is my Spring Boot Repository class

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MyCopRepo
{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbt;

    public String add(String userName, String systemLoginTime)
    {
        String userName1= userName;
    String systemLoginTime1=systemLoginTime; 
        //String systemLogoffTime1= systemLogoffTime;
        String query = "insert into mycopinsert(userName, systemLoginTime) values(?,?)";
        int i = jdbt.update(query, userName1, systemLoginTime1);
        if(i>0)
        {
            return "Inserted Successfully";
        }
        return "Not Inserted";
    }
}
```

=============================================

```
This is my Controller class:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyCopController
{
    @Autowired
    MyCopRepo ar;

    @PostMapping("/insert/{userName}/{systemLoginTime}")
    public String myCop(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, @PathVariable("systemLoginTime") String systemLoginTime)
    {
        return ar.add(userName, systemLoginTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, instead of passing as parameter just get the login time before make the query to the database.

```
    public String add(String userName)
    {
        String userName1= userName;
        String systemLoginTime=java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        //String systemLogoffTime1= systemLogoffTime;
        String query = "insert into mycopinsert(userName, systemLoginTime) values(?,?)";
        int i = jdbt.update(query, userName1, systemLoginTime1);
        if(i>0)
        {
            return "Inserted Successfully";
        }
        return "Not Inserted";
    }
}
```

You should also encapsulate the code in the main, creating methods to group content (instead of comments before each part), it is more understandable and easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your project to use Hibernate & Springboot and your solution becomes:

```
@postmapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody LoginEventRequestBody request) {

   LoginEvent event = new LoginEvent();

   event.setUsername(request.getUserName);
   event.setTimeStamp(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
   loginEventService.save(event);
   return "successfully logged login event";

}
```

Essentially, you will want to separate your login logic from your logging logic. After the user successfully logs in log the login event. 
you can still use path variables. I personally just find this cleaner

How to Set this up
**LoginEventRequestBody 

LoginEvent

LoginEventController

LoginEventService

LoginEventRepository

application.properties**

**LoginEventRequestBody.java**

```
package org.app.loginEvent;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(builder = LoginEventRequestBody.Builder.class)
@Value.Style(
    visibility = Value.Style.ImplementationVisibility.PACKAGE,
    builderVisibility = Value.Style.BuilderVisibility.PUBLIC
)
public interface LoginEventRequestBody {

    String getUserName();

    class Builder extends ImmutableLoginEventRequestBody.Builder {
    }

    static LoginEventRequestBody.Builder builder() {
        return new LoginEventRequestBody.Builder();
    }

}
```

**LoginEvent.java**

```
package org.app.loginEvent;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "login_event")
public class LoginEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private Timestamp timestamp;  

    public LoginEvent() {
    }

    public LoginEvent(String userName, Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**LoginEventController**

```
package org.app.loginEvent;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("events")
public class LoginEventController {

    private final LoginEventService loginEventService;

    public LoginEventController(LoginEventService loginEventService) {
        this.loginEventService = loginEventService;
    }

    @postmapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequestBody request) {

       LoginEvent event = new LoginEvent();

       event.setUsername(request.getUserName);
       event.setTimeStamp(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
       loginEventService.save(event);
       return "successfully logged login event";

    }
}
```

**LoginEventService**

```
package org.app.loginEvent;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class LoginEventService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginEventRepository loginEventRepository;

    public void save(LoginEventloginEvent) {
        loginEventRepository.save(loginEvent);
    }
}
```

**LoginEventRepository**

```
package org.app.loginEvent;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface LoginEventRepository extends JpaRepository<LoginEvent, Long> {
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#--------------------------------------------------
#mysql
#--------------------------------------------------
spring.datasource.username              =root
spring.datasource.password              =root
spring.datasource.url                   =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.driverClassName       =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto           =update
```

When your user logsIn,
Make a request to the event tracker

HTTP METHOD

```
POST
```

URL Endpoint

```
http://localhost:8080/events/login
```

Request body

```
{
  userName:"userNameOfThePersonTryingToLogIn"
}


#now check your database and you will find the event has logged
#repeat this process for your logout event
```

Comment: In LoginEventRequestBody showing an error error:"ImmutableLoginEventRequestBody.Builder"

Comment: run mvn clean install and that should do the trick. It needs to compile so that it builds the immutable class from the interface.